# WD External Harddisk turning on and off repeatedly

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, hard-drive-failure, portable-harddrive

It's a 5yrs+ old 3TB external harddisk running fine until a couple of months ago when I had a power outage.
After that, it stopped functioning properly. It stays on (with all the data intact), and then after a random amount of time (from 5 mins - 1 hr) it turns off automatically, and gets stuck in the loop of ON-OFF pings again and again repeatedly and doesn't stays stable at all and I cannot access the data then cause of this.

What could be the problem here? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for power outage could be several:

- Tripping MCB
- ELCB tripping
- RCCB tripping
- Power outage from the power line
- Power outage because there is a lightning strike.

If you are getting a power outage because of lightning strikes that could be fatal for your electronics.

If that's the cause, there is little almost nothing you can do. If the inside data is cost you around a thousand dollars or maybe a hundred thousand dollars, you can try to go data recovery service (see the certified one, do not go to a shoddy place)

If you are unsure because the data is too personal or maybe it will make a good fortune for the ones who look into it, you can try to do it yourself:

- buy the same HDD (brand, model, capacity)
- Have a clean room.
- Buy proper tools such as a screwdriver set, ESD safe gloves, ESD safe pad (solder pad, project pad as long as ESD safe), Anti-static wrist bracelet, or maybe grounding yourself :)
- Open both HDD (the bad and the good one).
- When you open it up, you can see there is a converter from USB to SATA

Basically, External HDD is an internal HDD with a USB to SATA converter :)

[image: Inside external HDD]
The red circle is the converter

Change the bad one with the good one. And try to connect it. See if it works.

If it doesn't work proceed to the next step:

- Try to open the logic board of your bad HDD. Replace it with the good one. PS: **careful with the solder joint for the motor.**
  [image: The HDD]
  The Yellow circle is the logic board of your HDD.

That's why I said to buy the same brand, model, and capacity for the second way :)

IF you did it and it still somehow broken, pray to GOD and burn that HDD :))

Joking, you can try to put the platter inside to the good ones, and put all back to the good one (logic board, converter) there is an issue too with HDD spindle didn't work properly or the platter sensor is broken.

[All pictures from here](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/3abn35/external_hdds_are_just_internal_drives_with_a/)

If you did it send me the result :)